# How to detect silverlight support?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I wanted to detect whether silverlight is supported on given browser or not. I've noticed that silverlight.js detects whether Silverlight is installed, but detecting whether it has been installed is different to detecting whether it CAN be installed.

For example - I wanted to show link to install silverlight but it only make sense  if given browser supports it. I also dont want to use helper js file Silverlight.supportedUserAgent.js since this is unreliable and not future-proof.

Comment: Using Silverlight is not future proof. Your best bet is sniffing for a user agent which matches [this table](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx?reason=unsupportedbrowser&_helpmsg=ChromeVersionDoesNotSupportPlugins#), which is presumably what `Silverlight.supportedUserAgent` does

Comment: Yes I know that. I have other work around for new browsers. This is I am doing for IE

Comment: There's your answer then. Silverlight is not even supported in Edge, use the user agent sniff because from now on, no browser is ever going to *add* support for Silverlight.

Comment: Hmmm...I see. so out of luck.